# java.lang.LinkageError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl

Tags: grails, soap

I found the solution that I have to exclude the   saaj-impl.jar 
I'm using wildfly 9.0.1 and the java version is 1.8
And My Project is based on grails with IntelliJ IDE
SO I do not know from which file and how should I exclude the  saaj-impl.jar So that , when I'll deploy , My war file will not include the  saaj-impl.jar from wildfly module

Comment: Do you need to exclude it from artifact? You could check it in "Project Structure | Artifacts"

Answer (score 0):

I got a simillar issue, but I use JBoss 6.x and what I find is here.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s33/sh/387e596e-b92d-434d-8099-314ad9160652/cf36bc5c4439f0d9

In grails project directory -> web-app folder -> folder WEB-INF, I create a file named jboss-deployment-structure.xml and I copied structure page says.

Other thing you can test is..... in your grails project directory -> conf directory -> BuildConfig.groovy  add this 2 lines in dependencies section:

- runtime ("com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.2.5") { excludes("javax.xml.soap:saaj-api","com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl",":org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex")}
- compile group: 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj', name: 'saaj-impl', version: '1.3.2'*

I hope this works for you.